# How can I optimize this script to update my database more quickly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I am trying to solve a problem by searching and combining a lot of different code snippets to allow for a update section on my database. I have two ranges one to collect data and one to clear, when you initiate the function it should read the lines with data, add date and email of the user then append each row to the end of a output sheet. Appending multiple rows has been an issue and this works but not very quickly.

Is there a way to optimize this so it runs without crashing the sheet everytime.

Tried this:

```
function updatebutton() {
 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();




// Confirm Update Submission
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const response = ui.alert(
  'Update Submittion','Are you sure you would like to submit this update?',
ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);


//Collect the data.
const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("sourceRange");
const cleanUpdate = ss.getRangeByName("cleanUpdate");
//console.log(formulas);
const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues().filter(e=>e.join().replace(/,/g, "").length);
console.log(sourceVals);


// gather current dts and user email
const date = new Date();
const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();


const data = [[date, email]].concat(sourceVals);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = [date, email, ...data[i]];
}
console.log(data);



// Append the data
const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Output");


//Clear the source data
cleanUpdate.clearContent();






// Process the user's response.
if (response === ui.Button.OK) {
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  destinationSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
}
ss.toast("Update Submitted: Player(s) Updated and added to the Update Log")
Logger.log('Update Submitted');
} else if(response === ui.Button.CANCEL) {
Logger.log('Update Not Submitted');
} else {
Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
}




};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you be so kind as to share with us a sample spreadsheet so that we may replicate it on our side? Also, please include the range definition of `"sourceRange"` and `"cleanUpdate"`.

Comment: Sure! 
Player List tab contains the input range 


_sourceRange_: 'Player List'!O3:Y5759 



_cleanUpdate_: 'Player List'!N3:Y5759

If you click update next to a player they move into the sourceRange.
Here is the [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zObG_6769MMASjNIliKvUbGD49rFJ9XZnvz_uWwEe0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You should show what you tried, show similar questions found on this site and why they don't meet your needs and make the question specific. P.S.  There is a sister site specialized on doing code reviews : [codereview.se]. Before posting a question ensure that you have read the how-to ask a good question guidelines including the linked resources.

Comment: The `appendRow()` method is convenient, but slow. Try to replicate it by finding the last empty row and then use the [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) method to write all of your data at once–not in a loop.

Comment: What is your actual issue? "*How can I optimize this script to update my database more quickly*" and "Is there a way to optimize this so it runs without crashing the sheet everytime.*" are very different situations... which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recommendation:

Change the `appendRow()` to `setValues()` and for loop to `map()` to lessen the run time. You can also remove `console.log()` and `Logger.log()` if you want.

```
function updatebutton() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Confirm Update Submission
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const response = ui.alert(
          'Update Submittion', 'Are you sure you would like to submit this update?',
            ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  //Collect the data.
    const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("sourceRange");
    const cleanUpdate = ss.getRangeByName("cleanUpdate");
    const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues().filter(e => e.join().replace(/,/g, "").length);
 
  // gather current dts and user email
    const date = new Date();
    const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var data = sourceVals.map(x => [date, email, ...x]); // instead of using for loop, you can use map function
 
  // Append the data
    const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
 
  //Clear the source data
    cleanUpdate.clearContent();
 
  // Process the user's response.
    if (response === ui.Button.OK) {
        destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); // instead of appendRow you can use the getRange().setValues()
  ss.toast("Update Submitted: Player(s) Updated and added to the Update Log")
  Logger.log('Update Submitted');  
  } else if (response === ui.Button.CANCEL) {
  Logger.log('Update Not Submitted');  
  } else {    
  Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');  
  }
  }
```

### References:

- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)